# Need to use Cookie instead of Session for auth in Zend 1

Tags: php, authentication, zend-framework, session-cookies

I have a app with zend 1, there is a auth example

```
$adapter = $this->getAuthAdapter($form->getValues());
$auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
$result = $auth->authenticate($adapter);
```

`Zend_Auth` uses Session storage, I want to change it and use `Cookie` instead of `Session`

Is there any way to do this with config or I must change Zend Storage ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic answer to your question is here in the documentation [Zend Auth: Implementing Customized Storage](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.auth.introduction.html#zend.auth.introduction.persistence.custom). As you've discovered the default storage is session based and there are no other options but as explained in this chapter you can write your own implementation.

I wrote an cookie implementation once for an application and it's pretty simple. If I can find it again I may be able to make it available on github.

Comment: I wrote the same kinda thing for token based authentication (for a web service).